# What is the maximum amount of Dreadpoints you can earn in Ratchet: Gladiator?

Tags: ratchet-deadlocked

In Ratchet: Gladiator (Deadlocked in the US), you can earn Dreadpoints for completing challenges, campaigns and bonus objectives.

They are used primarily as a means to gate levels and missions in order to make you follow a semi-linear path of progression, but they are also used as an in-game ranking of how well you are faring against other Gladiators. Replaying challenges will earn you extra Dreadpoints, but after a couple of replays they stop giving points, meaning there is a finite amount of points between story, challenges and re-plays.

What is the maximum amount of Dreadpoints one can earn on a single playthrough?

Answer (score -2):

This game does not seem to be that explored, so you probably won't find a definite answer, however There is one interesting video where a player achieved over 3 million points.

[image: score]

While I don't own the game myself and can't decompile it, It is very likely the score is a [32-bit signed integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit#Range_for_storing_integers). This means the maximum amount is 2,147,483,647 before it will overflow to the number 0.

Comment: There is a finite amount of points though, you cannot simply keep earning them: after beating a challenge 3 times you will no longer earn any points from beating it again, thus I highly doubt we can make it into the billions in order to overflow an int. Also, can you link to the video?

Comment: @Robotnik the picture is a hyperlink

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question, which is "How many points *total* (which means, across all missions), can be earned in a single playthrough of Ratchet: Gladiators/Deadlocked?) Your picture shows 3 million points for ONE mission, which, while it's a significant number, isn't the maximum possible amount of Dreadlock points.